# How do I get symbol files for Java.exe/jvm.dll to analyse crash core dump files?

Tags: java, websphere, coredump

I have a Java application running on a Websphere application server. When I analyse the system crash core dump file, I get some info like this:

```
ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for J9THR23.dll
```

How can I get symbol files for Java?

Thanks in advance.

More details are here:

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for J9THR23.dll - 
*************************************************************************
***                                                                   ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Your debugger is not using the correct symbols                 ***
***                                                                   ***
***    In order for this command to work properly, your symbol path   ***
***    must point to .pdb files that have full type information.      ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Certain .pdb files (such as the public OS symbols) do not      ***
***    contain the required information.  Contact the group that      ***
***    provided you with these symbols if you need this command to    ***
***    work.                                                          ***
***                                                                   ***
***    Type referenced: ntdll!_PEB                                    ***
***                                                                   ***
*************************************************************************
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for j9jit23.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for java.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for j9gc23.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for jvm.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for jclscar_23.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for j9ute23.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for J9PRT23.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for j9vm23.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for DBGHELP.DLL -
```

Alice Gong

Comment: I never look into the dumps from websphere. usually the application logs have all the information that you need to determine what blew up the java app.  what are you looking for ?

Answer (score 5):

You can get a DEBUG build of the JDK at this site.

http://download.java.net/jdk6/

Look for jdk-6u12-ea-bin-b03-windows-i586-debug-22*dec*2008.jar, 91.47 MB

It includes .pdb files

Comment: I believe the files offered here are not true PDB files, but instead are a full build of the Java binaries, with different options for compilation, that happens to include PDB files.  But these won't help look at an existing dump taken with the production JVM.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the debugger is looking for PDB files, and as far as I can tell debug information for java application doesn't come as PDB files. PDB files are generated by VisualStudio when creating Windows native applications, so it seems the debugger is looking for the application server's debug symbols. Don't know if WebSphere comes with its own debug version. On the other hand, if you want debug symbols for a java app you only need to recompile it with the `-g` option.